# How to prevent checking internet at startup

Tags: kernel-startup, version-11

Every time I start *Mathematica* 11.1, or restart a session after `Quit`, it takes about 20 seconds on my rMBP 2014 MacOS X 10.10 for the kernel to start up.  I just figured out (by switching off my wifi) that this annoying wait time is due to the kernel checking the internet at startup.  Without wifi, the kernel launches quickly.

Why is the *Mathematica* 11.1 kernel checking the internet each time I launch the kernel? and is there an option to switch it off?  It's annoying to have to turn off my wifi before starting/restarting *Mathematica*.

Comment: Yes, there is an option under Preferences -> Internet & Mail.  I think it's the same as the `$AllowInternet` variable.  But a 20 s startup time does not sound normal.

Comment: @Szabolcs. I'm pretty much experiencing the same slow startup as the OP with OS X 10.10.2. My experience is turning off Internet access does not cure the problem.

Comment: @m_goldberg Apparently, switching off the internet doesn't cure my problem either.  It still takes 20 seconds to load.  (Once it took 2 minutes!)